# EPEL 7 proftp package only outdated version available 1.3.5e

Tags: yum, package-management, proftpd, epel

Im a curious why there is no new version for the epel-x86_64 ftp server package proftp in the epel 7 repo:

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/proftpd-1.3.5e-10.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

There is only verion 1.3.5e avaiable from 09/Apr/2017.
The latest version is 1.3.7a is 21/Jul/2020.

Im am Using Amazon Linux 2 with proftp to host a ftp server.

What can I do beside manully compiling it? I want to update proftp via yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Linux distributions are not designed to be bleeding edge, but to provide long term stability and support of all components they ship.

Necessary security updates (and sometimes new features) get backported rather  upgrading to a newer upstream version with new features.

https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HermanB's answer I understood now, that the version number of the official proftp package (1.3.7) and the epel package (1.3.5.) does not mean, that bug fixes are not fixed.

When I looked at the changelog I discovered that the team merges important updates and fixes security issues:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/7/ppc64le/Packages/p/proftpd-1.3.5e-10.el7.ppc64le.html